About some properties of the even lattice
Let $V$ be a finite dimensional real vector space and let $(\cdot,\cdot)$ be non-degenerate symmetric bilinear form on $V$. Consider an "even lattice" $l$ in $V$, i.e., an Abelian group $l\subset V$ of maximal rank such that $(x,y)\in\mathbf{Z}$, and $(x,x)\in 2\mathbf{Z}$, for all $x,y\in l$. With the bilinear form $(\cdot,\cdot),$ the dual vector space $V^*$ can be identified with $V$ and consquently the dual lattice $l^*$ can be identify with a lattice in $V$, i.e., we can set $l^*:=\{x\in V: (x,l)\subset\mathbf{Z}\}$. I have the following two problems:
$(1)$ I want to prove that $(l^*)^*=l$. I'm ok with $l\subseteq (l^*)^*$. To prove $(l^*)^*\subseteq l$, if $x\in(l^*)^*:=\{x\in V:(x,l^*)\subset\mathbf{Z}\}$, then $(x,l^*)\subset\mathbf{Z}$, thus $(x,l)\subset\mathbf{Z}$. Now, we remain to prove that  ''$(x,x)\subset2\mathbf{Z}$'', but I can't figure out this part.
$(2)$ I want to prove that $l^*/l$ is a finite Abelian group, it's clear for Abelian, but how can I say it is a finite group.
Thank you!

Is there something unclear with my answer (you unaccepted it)?

By the definition of $l$, it’s an free $\mathbf{Z}$-module of maximal rank satisfies $(x,y)\in\mathbf{Z}, (x,x)\in2\mathbf{Z}$. So, is the rank of $l$ always equal to dimension of $V$?

What exactly is your definition of lattice? You need to assume that $l$ is discrete. If $l$ is not full rank (i.e. does not span $V$), then there is a vector $v\ne0$ orthogonal to $l$ w.r.t. to $(-,-)$. Then $l+\Bbb Zv$ is still an even lattice, but has a larger rank

(1) is a general fact about lattices and does not require the assumption that $l$ is even or even $(l,l)\subseteq\Bbb Z$. We may assume that $V=\Bbb R^n$. Let $l=A\Bbb Z^n$ for some invertible real $n\times n$ matrix $A$ and let $B$ be symmetric such that $(x,y) = x^TBy$, i.e. $B_{ij}=(e_i,e_j)$. Then for $x\in \Bbb R^n$ we have \begin{align*}
x\in l^*&\Longleftrightarrow (x, Ae_i)\in\Bbb Z\text{ for $i=1,\dots,n$}\\
&\Longleftrightarrow x^TBAe_i\in\Bbb Z\text{ for $i=1,\dots,n$}\\
&\Longleftrightarrow (A^TBx)^Te_i\in\Bbb Z\text{ for $i=1,\dots,n$}\\
&\Longleftrightarrow A^TBx\in\Bbb Z^n\\
&\Longleftrightarrow x\in B^{-1}A^{-T}\Bbb Z^n
\end{align*}
So $l^*=B^{-1}A^{-T}\Bbb Z^n$. Applying this again shows that $(l^*)^*=B^{-1}(B^{-1}A^{-T})^{-T}\Bbb Z^n=A\Bbb Z^n=l$.
For (2) note that since $(l,l)\subseteq\Bbb Z$ we have $l\subseteq l^*$ and in general if $A$ is free abelian of finite rank and $B$ is a subgroup of the same rank, then $B$ is of finite index in $A$ (for example because $A/B$ is torsion and finitely generated, hence finite).
